# Trouble on having too many pages of code

Tags: html, css, web

What I am looking to do is to have a main page with a list of 20 or so photographs on it. When one of the images is clicked, I'd like it to open a new page with the description on that photo, a preview of that photo, and the option to buy it. Is the only way to do this is by writing a new page of code every time a new image is clicked, or is there a way every page can share the same code, while only changing the preview of the photo.

Comment: There are a multitude of ways to accomplish this task but Stack Overflow is a platform for asking a specific question about a specific problem, not broad how to do its. I suggest you look elsewhere for a solution.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that what you say can't be done with a front-end language, it requires more of a CMS to do such thing, requires back-end job with an engine (PHP as example) and database such as MySQL.
Please remember that the HTML is a Markup-Language not a programming language, it has no logic as "if and else"..
I hope that answered your question. <3